# How to set continuation indentation in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is the formatting I want to achieve:

```js
function x() {
    $elementOfSomething
            .find(".class")
            .remove();
}
```

This is the formatting VSCode does by default:

```js
function x() {
    $elementOfSomething
        .find(".class")
        .remove();
}
```

The default indentation is 4 spaces. In the second sample, the third and fourth lines are indented by 4 spaces in relation to the previous line. In the first sample, they are indented by 8 spaces. So I want to the default indentation to be 4 spaces but the continuation indentation to be 8 spaces. In NetBeans, there is the setting "continuation indentation" for this. Is there a way to achive such indenation behaviour in VSCode (for JS and Java)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS Code this setting is called "wrapping indent", and this setting is located within the Text Editor category of settings.

Sounds like you want to set your wrapping indent to the "deepIndent" option, which will relatively indent the wrapped line to the width of two tabs. For example, if your tab size setting is 4 spaces, a deepIndent will be 8 spaces.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/28555/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: deleted screenshot. thank you for letting me know.

Comment: From what I understand, wrapping indent is indentation for lines that get wrapped into multiple lines by the editor because they are too long. I think what OP asked is different.

Comment: @piuspbd agree, do you want to edit my answer or submit new one?

Comment: @TimStewart I don't think VS Code supports this feature atm